# How to use existing records in many-to-many relation and to avoid unique constraint violation (hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, unique-constraint

There are two classes, Person and Vehicle, in many-to-many relationship. If a new Person is created or a record of existing Person is updated (e.g. Vehicle records added) it would be desirable to use existing Vehicle record if it exists.

The question is how to achieve it. A query prior the insert or update is not an option because there are many threads which can update or insert.

At this moment the application checks unique constraint exception and when it is caught the new existing Vehicle object is replaced by one which is queried from the db by "registration" column. This solution is working however it seems to be kind of clumsy as there has to be a separate session created for each Vehicle record.

Is there any way how to achieve desired behaviour by hibernate annotations? Or completely different solution? Thanks.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name", name="NAME_KEY") })
public class Person  implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 3507716047052335731L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="PersonIdSeq")
  @SequenceGenerator( name = "PersonIdSeq", sequenceName="PERSON_ID_SEQ")
  private Long id;

  @Index(name="PERSON_NAME_IDX")
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Vehicle.class, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinTable(name="PERSON_VEHICLE_LNK", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="VEHICLE_ID"),
     uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"PERSON_ID", "VEHICLE_ID"}, name="person_vehicle_lnk_key")})
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="PersonVehicleLnkIdSeq")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "PersonVehicleLnkIdSeq", sequenceName="PERSON_VEHICLE_LNK_ID_SEQ")
  @CollectionId(columns = @Column(name="ID"), type=@Type(type="long"), generator = "PersonVehicleLnkIdSeq")
  private List<Vehicle> vehicle = new ArrayList<>();
  ...

@Entity
@Table( name = "VEHICLE", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="registration", name="REGISTRATION_KEY")}  )
public class Vehicle implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5592281235230216382L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="VehicleIdSeq")
  @SequenceGenerator( name = "VehicleIdSeq", sequenceName="VEHICLE_ID_SEQ")
  private Long id;

  @Index(name="REGISTRATION_IDX")
  private String registration;
  ...
```

Comment: In MySQL, that's `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Comment: Try the following: attempt to insert; if that fails, update. If there are concurrent deletes as well, this may take several rounds of attempts.

Comment: Thnaks. I'm sure this is a solution for the database level, but I would rather stay on ORM level.

Comment: You can do the update-retry loop at the object level.

Comment: Actually, as I stated in my question, I'm already doing it, but I'm not happy with the solution as for every Vehicle record a new Session has to be opened and if it fails it has to be rolled back and another new session has to be created to query the existing record from the table.

Comment: A session is unusable after a rollback?

Comment: Unfortunately yes: "If the Session throws an exception, the transaction must be rolled back and the session discarded. The internal state of the Session might not be consistent with the database after the exception occurs." [link]http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22961/discussion-between-miloxe-and-jan-dvorak)

Answer (score 1):

> A query prior the insert or update is not an option because there are many threads which can update or insert.

But this is how to do it.

If it is a performance problem (I don't think so) then consider about using a 2nd level cache. The first level can't handle this because it is bound to a session and you need at least one session per thread.

And then you need a version column in both `Person` and `Vehicle`.

In your application you already have the following problem: 1. User A loads a Person record. 2. User B loads the same Person record. 3. User A modifies the telephone number and saves the Person record. 4. User B modifies the Address and also saves the Person record. => Result: The modification (telephone number change) of User A is overwritten, the record has the old telephone number and nobody gets informed about this problem.

A version column avoids this problem. When there is a version column, in the step 4 Hibernate finds out the record was modified in meantime and throws an exception. This exception must be caught and User B must be told to reload the record and redo his address change. This forces a little extra work from user B (not much because this case seldom happens), but no information get lost and the database contains the correct information.

The same you have to do when no record was found on first reading, but on insert a constraint violation is caught. You already catch this error, but you don't inform the user, which you probably should do.

There is no easy solution in Hibernate level for this because the application logic has to treat this case (for example with informing the user).

Comment: Once a Person is inserted its name is constant and the same applies for the registration in the Vehicle class. Only List of Vehicles can be modified and this is done by automatic threads not by users.

Comment: When the insertion is done by automatic threads, then this case must be handles by the automatic thread. It depends of your application logic what to do when a record already exists. For the check of existence you have two possibilities: Either read before insert or catch the unique constraint violation. If you use a `StatelessSession`, then you still can use it after an exception.